# What's the benefit of advanced master election algorithms over bully algorithm?

Tags: cluster-computing, distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper, paxos, raft

I read how current master election algorithms like Raft, Paxos or Zab elect master on a cluster and couldn't understand why they use sophisticated algorithms instead of simple bully algorithm.

I'm developing a cluster library and use UDP Multicast for heartbeat messages. Each node joins a multicast address and also send datagram packets periodically to that address. If the nodes find out there is a new node that sends packets to this multicast address, the node is simply added to cluster and similarly when the nodes in the cluster don't get any package from a node, they remove it from the cluster. When I need to choose a master node, I simply iterate over the nodes in the cluster and choose the oldest one.

I read some articles that implies this approach is not effective and more sophisticated algorithms like Paxos should be used in order to elect a master or detect failures via heartbeat messages. I couldn't understand why Paxos is better for split-brain scenarios or other network failures than traditional bully algorithm because I can easily find out when quorum of nodes leave from the cluster without using Raft. The only benefit I see is the count of packets that each server have to handle; only master sends heartbeat messages in Raft while in this case each node has to send heartbeat message to each other. However I don't think this is a problem since I can simply implement similar heartbeat algorithm without changing my master election algorithm.

Can someone elaborate on that?

Comment: If you have a temporary split in your network that is later then sealed, nodes may disagree as to who is the oldest, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a theoretical perspective, Raft, Paxos and Zab are not leader election algorithms. They solve a different problem called consensus.

In your concrete scenario, the difference is the following. With a leader election algorithm, you can only guarantee that eventually one node is a leader. That means that during a period of time, multiple nodes might think they are the leader and, consequently, might act like one. In contrast, with the consensus algorithms above, you can guarantee that there is at most one leader in a logical time instant.

The consequence is this. If the safety of the system depends on the presence of a single leader, you might get in trouble relying only on a leader election. Consider an example. Nodes receive messages from the UDP multicast and do A if the sender is the leader, but do B if the sender is not the leader. If two nodes check for the oldest node in the cluster at slightly different points in time, they might see different leaders. These two nodes might then receive a multicast message and process it in different manners, possibly violating some safety property of the system you'd like to hold (eg, that all nodes either do A or B, but never one does A and another does B).

With Raft, Paxos, and Zab, you can overcome that problem since these algorithms create sort of logical epochs, having at most one leader in each of them.

Two notes here. First, the bully algorithm is defined for synchronous systems. If you really implement it as described in the paper by Garcia-Molina, I believe you might experience problems in your partially synchronous system. Second, the Zab algorithm relies on a sort of bully algorithm for asynchronous systems. The leader is elected by comparing the length of their histories (that minimizes the recovery time of the system). Once the leader is elected, it tries to start the Zab protocol, which in turn locks the epoch for the leader.